# MySQL: Trigger produces Table not found exception

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I have the following 2 database tables:
DEPT (**Dnumber** , Dname, Founded, Mgr_ssn, Budget)
EMPLOYEE (**Ssn**, Ename , Bdate, Dno, Salary)

and I want to create a trigger to ensure that no department has more than 8 employees.
here's what I written so far

```
    DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER ensure_dept_count_on_insert BEFORE insert on `EMPLOYEE`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DECLARE maxCount integer;
        set maxCount = (select count(*) as c from Employee where Dno = new.Dno);
        if maxCount = 9
        then SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Department cannot have more than 8 employees';
        end if;
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

The problem is that when I insert into EMPLOYEE, it gives me Table NOT found Exception and when dropping the trigger the insertion succeed.

Comment: Are table names case sensitive in your server?

Comment: Also, was the trigger created in the same database ?

Comment: I'm thinking exactly the same thing @UUeerdo... identifier case sensitivity *"it is best to adopt a consistent convention, such as always creating and referring to databases and tables using lowercase names. This convention is recommended for maximum portability and ease of use."*  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html  .(.. and for the love of all that is good and beautiful in this world, just StopWithTheCamelCase for table names!)

Comment: naming convention we adopt for triggers in MySQL, is to use a suffix after the table name `table_name_bi`  for the BEFORE INSERT trigger,  `_bu` for the BEFORE UPDATE,  `_ad` for AFTER DELETE, etc.

Comment: Thank you, you are right when I changed the Employee to EMPLOYEE insertion worked however it stills doesn't prevent the insertion.

Comment: Thank you all, it worked fine, Thank you